# like somebody to do something

Tags: sentence-construction

today in the internet  I read the sentence:

> "I don’t like the team to play like that for an hour" (Carlos Ancelotti)

Is this correct English? I think I've never heard this construction before and I'm not sure if it's correct. To me, it sounds pretty strange.

Comment: I don't like [something]. I don't like [the team to play that way for an hour] = I don't like the team's playing. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out which part of this construct you find "strange". _Like_ is being used as a [verb](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=like), and it essentially means that Carlos Ancelotti is bothered when his team plays in that way for an hour. It could mean they are playing badly in a game; it could also mean they are practicing in the heat and he is worried about heat exhaustion and dehydration.

Comment: Dude. IT's Carlo Ancelotti, not Carlos; Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Ancelotti

Answer (score 1):

I found this definition of the verb **like** on [*Macmillan Dictionary*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/like_46) that may be helpful:

> to prefer to do something in a particular way, or to prefer to have
>   something done in a particular way
>
> **like someone to do something:** *She likes us to hand our work in on time.*

As you might have figured out, what Carlos has basically said is "I don't want the team to play like that for an hour (because they didn't play well, maybe?)" He's not happy about the way they played because he likes them to do better than that.